# Catch Commandline error

Tags: c#

I am trying to catch an error with an incorrect commandline parameter for the application of form

```
Myapp.exe myFile.txt
```

The application however throws an "Unhandled exception - The path is not of legal form".

Below is my code and I am wondering why it does not show the message box as provided in the code? Thanks.

```
String[] cmdlineArgs = Environment.GetCommandLineArgs();

if (cmdlineArgs.Length == 2)
{
    try
    {
        if (File.Exists(cmdlineArgs[1].ToString()))
            ConfigParameters.SetConfigParameters(cmdlineArgs[1].ToString());
        else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Configuration file does not exist.Restarting...");
                Environment.Exit(1);
             }
     }
     catch (Exception ex)
     {

     }
```

Comment: try to remove that `.ToString()`

Comment: @Rubens: That will not help.  (However, he should do it anyway)

Comment: Tried removing ToString(). Does not work. Thanks.

Comment: step through your code, and check what the value of cmdlineArgs[1] actually is.  I'm guessing something isn't being set correctly when you run it.

Comment: [1] What is `ConfigParameters.SetConfigParameters`? [2] Which line is throwing the error, `File.Exists` or `SetConfigParameters`?

Answer (score 1):

If you pass an invalid path to `File.Exists` (such, `C:\D:/E:\`), you get that exception.

Comment: No unfortunately I dont and I cant figure whats wrong in my code.

Answer (score 0):

Check for improper characters in the file path (e.g. '>' <'>, etc...).

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.getinvalidfilenamechars.aspx
&
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.getinvalidpathchars.aspx

Answer (score 0):

You should modify your code like bellow is more better :D

```
String[] cmdlineArgs = Environment.GetCommandLineArgs();

if (cmdlineArgs.Length == 2)
{
    try
    {
        if (File.Exists(cmdlineArgs[1].ToString()))
            ConfigParameters.SetConfigParameters(cmdlineArgs[1].ToString());
     }
     catch (Exception ex)
     {
          MessageBox.Show("Configuration file does not exist.Restarting...");
          Environment.Exit(1);
     }
}
```

Because when your file path contain some special characters(<, >, ?, *, etc), the File.Exists() maybe throw exception as you see.